# had something (cleaned or clean)?

Tags: past-participles, causative-have

> He had the robot cleaned the house.

I wanna know whether this sentence has any error for following meaning : He ordered the robot to stop on its operation.

As following two have meaning like in the parentheses,

> He had the robot cleaned.(The robot was cleaned by him)
>
> He had the robot clean the house. (The robot did cleaning because of him)

putting 'cleaned' instead of 'clean' in the second one, I guessed rarely  possible though, makes 'cleaning' finished.

Comment: He had the robot cleaned = Someone other than he cleaned the robot at his behest.

Comment: Are you asking whether causative **had** + past participle **cleaned** + direct object **house** translates to "stop cleaning the house"? If so, the answer is no.  *He had the robot cleaned the house* is ungrammatical.  It is mixing a causative-passive construction (where robot is the patient of **cleaned**) with a transitive construction where **cleaned** has a second object,**house**.

Comment: The present participle is possible with causative **have**: She had her piano student **practicing** his scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He had the robot cleaned the house.

He had the robot cleaned.

He had the robot clean the house.

The first sentence is incorrect grammatically.

The second and the third sentences are correct grammatically.  The second one implies that he caused somebody to clean the robot, whereas the third one means that he caused the robot to clean the house.